# Why Posted on IIS project, config file configuration error occurred

Tags: asp.net

When I publish a `ASP.NET` project, it prompts configuration error，Fifteenth row  as:

```
Tip:Already defined zone or group name 'applicationSettings'. You can only define it updates its configuration hierarchy .
```

I need your help，thank you !

```
</sectionGroup>
row 14:     </sectionGroup>
row  15:     <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"   type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System,    Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
row  16:       <section name="WebTemplate.Properties.Settings"  type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.2,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"   requirePermission="false" />
row  17:       <section name="VPA.Properties.Settings"  type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"   requirePermission="false" />
```

Please help me to figure out why I am getting the configuration error.

Comment: 15:   <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config needs to be a valid "xml" file.

Try to name your section group like that and don't forget to close xml element :

```
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="WebTemplate.Properties.Settings"  type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.2,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"   requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="VPA.Properties.Settings"  type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"   requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

( you can have more that one different sectionGroup in your configSections,but only one with the same name )